# Unable to get only the current user name from Firebase

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a web app. I can get the details from firebase. 
Goal: To get the username of current logged in user and display it in a label.
Current scenario: I am able to get the usernames. However, the problem is, if there are 3 users in Firebase database, it is taking and appending the usernames of all the users.

Here are the screenshots:
[image: browser console output]

See that, in the screenshot, there are two usernames, Pasuad and Karthik Babu. I am logged in as Pasuad, it shows the username as Pasuad Karthik Babu, where as it should show only Pasuad. [image: firebase console output]

Here is the code snippet:

```
 var config = {
apiKey: "AIzaSyDefsNT1f5-MSKvlh-JnoeJQxfWPKgnZto",
authDomain: "woofydesk-9fe8b.firebaseapp.com",
databaseURL: "https://woofydesk-9fe8b.firebaseio.com",
projectId: "woofydesk-9fe8b",
storageBucket: "woofydesk-9fe8b.appspot.com",
messagingSenderId: "1000344965487"
  };

firebase.initializeApp(config);


  var rootRef = firebase.database().ref('WoofyDesktop/UserList');
  rootRef.on("child_added", snap => {

var username = snap.child("username").val();
 $("#username").append("<a href='javascript:void(0)'><label>" + username + "</label></a>");

  console.log(username);

  });
```

Any insights or suggestions are greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading some user information stored in your real time database, if you only want the current logged-In user information, then you have to use the firebase auth service: have a look at its documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start
you do something like:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {

  // User is signed in.
  if (user) {
    console.log(user.displayName + " has logged in!");
  }
  // No user is signed in.
  else {
    console.log("user is logged out");

  }
});
```

}